# Are there any differences between Class and Object Functions defining methods?

Tags: javascript

Are the two defining methods pretty much the same? Is there anything I should watch out for?

```
// A.
function Dog(name, color, numLegs) {
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
  this.numLegs = numLegs;
}

Dog.prototype.greet = function() {
  return 'Bark!';
}
```

```
// B.
class Dog {
  constructor(name = '', color = '', numLegs = 0) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
  }

  greet() {
    return 'Bark!';
  }
}
```

I'm refactoring an old application and I'm wondering if it's safe to restructure all existing object functions from (A) to (B) as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` in JavaScript is a syntactic sugar of constructor functions. When you work with functions, you are dealing with prototypes and prototypal inheritance, whereas in a `class` it's more of coupling these actions together within a blueprint, which again makes use of functions and prototypes under the hood. In the first case, the function `greet` is a prototype property of the function `Dog`, meaning the instance of `Dog` will be able to access the method `greet`, and the same applies to the second case as well. (Make sure to use the `new` keyword when instantiating objects in both cases).

Answer (score 2):

A js class is a beautified way of writing your first bit of code.
So yes these two syntaxes do exactly the same thing.